# Does anyone know what this means or the origins of this artwork?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context, simplified-characters, phrase-meaning

Need help with where the signature stamp came from.  Deng Shaoxin has been translated, but I'm not sure where to go from there as this is a very common surname.  Translation of the rest seems to be Christian in nature.  Is this supposed to represent Jesus?

[image: Christian? Watercolor Art work]
[image]

Comment: It looks like a very "Chineselized" version of a Bible painting. I guess the top left 3 is supposed to be Jesus. With that beard, that baby, minorities, and women around, I feel like this is depicting Jesus preaching the gospel.

Comment: If you have a picture of the words, my guesses can be confirmed.

Comment: We were able to translate the phrase, and it seems to be a bible verse, but the translation is shotty and I do not recognize it from KJV of bible

Comment: I mean, I am willing to help you locate the verse if you have a zoomed-in picture of the words written on the painting.

Comment: Ok I added another picture.

Comment: It is Mat 28:18-20. The first 4 lines are the verses. The last line is the verse label. But I cannot Identify the first two characters in the last line.

Comment: Logically it should be "Saint, (St), Mathew, i.e either 圣者 or 圣徒. From that cursive script, it looks more like the former?

Answer (score 1):

耶稣进前來对他们说:天上地下所有的权柄都赐
给我了，所以你们要去使万民作我的门徒，奉父、子
、圣灵的名给他们施洗， 凡我所吩咐你的，都教训他
们遵守，我就常与你们同在，直到世界的末了。

?? 馬太福音 二十八章 十八之二十節

(?? is not clear I can't understand. Something like 恭奉?)

Its from 馬太福音(Gospel of Matthew)  28:18-20

Then Jesus came to them and said, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me. Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit, and teaching them to obey everything I have commanded you. And surely I am with you always, to the very end of the age.”

Comment: The first line should read: 耶稣进前來對他们说 ...

Comment: Oh yes, thanks lol, I always use traditional Chinese, seldom use simplified-chinese
  , I've update it.

Comment: it is ‘十八至二十節’。